# How to register for Fandango API key

Tags: api-key

I feel stupid asking this, but does anyone know how to register for a Fandango API key?

I'm trying to make a silly little app that pulls up available movie tickets on Fandango. There's tons of documentation on the internet about how to use their API, but nothing about registering. I tried their registration link on their site, but it just says "Registration is currently disabled":
https://developer.fandango.com/member/register

Do they not allow anyone to get a new API key anymore? Or am I just doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2):

From Fandango:

> Unfortunately we don't currently provide direct access without significant anticipated scale of ticket sales.  We do offer a couple of alternative options.
>
> You can access a variety of links and widgets via our presence on Commission Junction.
>
> Alternatively, you can license showtime data from Gracenote or CinemaSource, and through that license, you'd be able to link directly to our site.